# Why is the ViewController taking up only half of the screen?

Tags: ios, swift, view, xcode-storyboard

In some applications I'm building in the new Xcode beta 11.2, some View Controllers created from storyboard and view code are launched taking only partial size of the screen. Why is it happening?

Some additional information:
- I've changed the info.plist file argument UIRequiresFullScreen to true.
- I've also set the proper ViewController in the info.plist file, so it's launching correctly, but smaller.
- No changes were made in the AppDelegate.Swift, neither at SceneDelegate.Swift.

[image]

Comment: Try to set the BG Color for your `ViewController` and I would also recommend you to debug via `Debug View Hierarchy` in `XCode` to see which view has the frame.

Comment: Do you have a [launch screen storyboard](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/responding_to_the_launch_of_your_app#3222089)?

Comment: default presentation style in iOS 13 is "sheet", depending on your setting, it could be what happens. See: https://medium.com/@hacknicity/view-controller-presentation-changes-in-ios-13-ac8c901ebc4e

Comment: @harish, the window is the one smaller than it should.

Comment: @TylerTheCompiler, I don't. Why? As far I was concerned, the Window instantiation was made by any initial .storyboard

Comment: @KirilS. I don't happen to choose presentation style for the view controller. It's being pushed directly from the application.

Comment: @gabrielrf97 Not having a launch screen storyboard will cause this. Add one and your app will take up the full screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [launch screen storyboard](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/responding_to_the_launch_of_your_app) to make your app take up the full device screen size. If you don't, the app will run in a smaller window and there will be black bars above and below your app's content.